# p:webcam warning

Tags: primefaces, webcam

I have a JSF web application which uses a webcam to capture the image using Primefaces `p:webcam`.

It works fine except the fact, giving the following warning every time the page loads on computers that do not have a webcam.

```
Webcam.js Error: Could not access webcam: NotFoundError: Requested device not found NotFoundError: Requested device not found
```

How can I suppress that warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to separate the part of the page from the page given to all users.

For example, the page has a link "Click here to capture". Direct it to a new page or display a dialog with a part that is rendered only when going to capture the image.